# Rowkey is null when celledit with LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 6.1. I have implemented LazyDataModel and I am able to load the rows, owever, when I update a cell, the method onCellEdit is called  but event.rowKey is always null.

```
     <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nessun record trovato."
                                         style="margin-top: 50px" id="cars" var="produit"
                                         value="#{gecomparBean.lazyModel}"  
                                         editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable"
                                         filteredValue="#{gecomparBean.filteredCars}" 
                                         rows="10"
                                         lazy="true"
                                         scrollRows="10"
                                         scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="250"


                                         resizableColumns="true" resizeMode="expand"
                                         draggableColumns="true" 

                                         rowStyleClass="#{produit.id == gecomparBean.selectedObject.id ? 'selectedRow' : null}"
                                         >



                                <p:ajax event="colReorder"
                                        listener="#{gecomparBean.onColumnReorder}" />
                                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{gecomparBean.onCellEdit}"  
                                        oncomplete="updateTable()"  update=":form:remote" />
```

Managed Bean: [Session scoped]

```
 wrapper.setSession(activeSession.getId());
        lazyModel = new LazyProductDataModel(wrapper);
```

LazyProductDataModel

```
public class LazyProductDataModel extends LazyDataModel<ProductSessionDTO> implements Serializable {

private List<ProductSessionDTO> products;
private ProductSearchWrapper wrapper;

public LazyProductDataModel(ProductSearchWrapper wrapp) throws RestRequestException {
    super();
    wrapper = wrapp;

}

@Override
public ProductSessionDTO getRowData(String rowKey) {
    for (ProductSessionDTO car : getProducts()) {
        if (car.getId() == (Long.parseLong(rowKey))) {
            return car;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(ProductSessionDTO car) {
    return car.getId();
}

@Override
public List<ProductSessionDTO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    List<ProductSessionDTO> data = new ArrayList<ProductSessionDTO>();
    try {
        System.out.println("First " + first + " Max " + pageSize);
        wrapper.setFirst(first);
        wrapper.setPageSize(pageSize);
        products=ServiceUtils.getInstance().getProducts(wrapper);

        if (getProducts() != null) {

            Comparator<ProductSessionDTO> lengthComparator = new Comparator<ProductSessionDTO>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(ProductSessionDTO o1, ProductSessionDTO o2) {
                    return Long.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId());
                }
            };
            Collections.sort(products, lengthComparator);

        }
    } catch (RestRequestException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LazyProductDataModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    data = products;

    //rowCount
    int dataSize = data.size();
    this.setRowCount(1000);

    //paginate
    if (dataSize > pageSize) {
        try {
            return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
        }
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

}

Note: I found a post which mentioned that we need to remove the rowkey in order for the getRowKey() to get called automatically - so I have removed that attribute.

Comment: what **do** you have in the event?

Comment: this may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790692/editable-datatable-rowkey-null